Why was the US so adamant about dismantling colonial empires during and after WW2 despite their seemingly contradictory racial and ethnic views?
I'm reading Antony Beevor's "The Second World War" and am increasingly confused by the seemingly contradictory American views on foreign peoples and their independence in relation to their colonial status.
It is well known that the US wanted to dismantle European colonial empires after the war and wasn't particularly thrilled when its forces were used to "save", e.g., British colonies. However, given contemporary American views on race and ethnicity, this stance greatly confuses me.
The various people under British, French, etc. imperial government were considered just as inferior and incompetent as the Black population at home; "nigger" was used to describe North African Arabs during the war and Filipinos just 40 years earlier (I could find no evidence for its usage against Filipinos during the conflict). Many American soldiers also had no qualms about shooting North African Arabs for entertainment, which is a particularly stark contrast to their behaviour when dealing with Europeans. American racial attitudes towards the Chinese and Japanese are also no secret.
All in all, these attitudes seem to mesh quite well with the "White Man's Burden" views of the British, whereby the hapless and inferior races of the world require European oversight to prosper. I've seen T.E.D.'s answer here, but this doesn't fully answer my question.
In summary, why were the Americans so adamant about self-determination for people they considered inferior and, in the case of the Black American population, "unworthy"/not-deserving of even full citizen rights?

All peoples like to look at themselves through rose tinted glasses, whilst expecting high standards amongst others. As the european empires started to fall (or be dismantled) and often fell under the influence of the soviets, America started to change it's policies as it realised that making your friends weaker wasn't always a good idea!

This is a bit of a fundamental misunderstanding. The people of the USA (who gave a crap about foreign affairs, which was probably always a minority) were fully in favor of people of non-European (and in fact European) ethnicities running their own countries. There were a rather lot of Americans who were personally against having those same people have much of a say in running America, but that's quite different. The history of Liberia is a great example of the principle.

I think it is unreasonable to expect foreign policy to be consistent with arbitrary values.  The goal of most policy is to obtain the upper hand by judging others to be inadequate.  Anti-colonialism fulfills that objective quite well.   But domestic policy should be judged on how well it benefits me.  If I have to expert effort, then it isn't a value, it is a wooly headed idealistic notion proposed only by fringe elements.  Humor aside, this question is (IMHO), unanswerable. because it is predicated on a false assumption (that policy and values are consistent in a democracy)

with no disrespect to OP, " seemingly contradictory American views" is an effective synonym for "Water is wet, the Habsburgs are falling and the middle class is rising"

I think the focus on WWII makes the answer more difficult to see. Looking at the history of American relations with the Philippines, Japan, and China between (to pick two random dates) Commodore Perry and the USS Panay incident is very illustrative.

"despite their seemingly contradictory racial and ethnic views?"  White's who wanted to abolish slavery rarely thought that blacks were equal to whites.


given contemporary American views on race and ethnicity, this stance greatly confuses me.

The US opposition to European imperialism was never framed in terms of anti-racism. It was always explicitly about access to markets, and then later, anti-Communism.
Even the US State Department's own website makes this clear when it explains why European countries resisted decolonization and why the US was so willing to aid newly-independent countries economically:

Nearly all of the United States’ European allies believed that after
their recovery from World War II their colonies would finally provide
the combination of raw materials and protected markets for finished
goods that would cement the colonies to Europe. Whether or not this
was the case, the alternative of allowing the colonies to slip away,
perhaps into the United States’ economic sphere or that of another
power, was unappealing to every European government interested in
postwar stability. Although the U.S. Government did not force the issue, it encouraged the European imperial powers to negotiate an early withdrawal from their overseas colonies. The United States granted independence to the Philippines in 1946.
However, as the Cold War competition with the Soviet Union came to dominate U.S. foreign policy concerns in the late 1940s and 1950s, the Truman and Eisenhower Administrations grew increasingly concerned that as the European powers lost their colonies or granted them independence, Soviet-supported communist parties might achieve power in the new states. This might serve to shift the international balance of power in favor of the Soviet Union and remove access to economic resources from U.S. allies. Events such as the Indonesian struggle for independence from the Netherlands (1945–50), the Vietnamese war against France (1945–54), and the nationalist and professed socialist takeovers of Egypt (1952) and Iran (1951) served to reinforce such fears, even if new governments did not directly link themselves to the Soviet Union. Thus, the United States used aid packages, technical assistance and sometimes even military intervention to encourage newly independent nations in the Third World to adopt governments that aligned with the West. The Soviet Union deployed similar tactics in an effort to encourage new nations to join the communist bloc, and attempted to convince newly decolonized countries that communism was an intrinsically non-imperialist economic and political ideology. Many of the new nations resisted the pressure to be drawn into the Cold War, joined in the “nonaligned movement,” which formed after the Bandung conference of 1955, and focused on internal development.


This has nothing to do with racial or ethnic views, or rights of nations etc. The main reason is economic: they wanted the markets to be open. The market of a colony is usually protected by the metropole.

This is the correct answer, but it needs elaboration and sources.

not sure if this is correct, the British Empire operated largely on the basis of free-trade. the french empire, not-so-much

This is what Mead would call a "Hamiltonian" foreign policy view. I think its accurate as far as that school of thought goes, but that branch  is(per Mead) less than 1/4 of Americans.

@T.E.D. Well, a count of hands raised does not establish truth. ;-) Given Brian's quote and the evidence of US post-war foreign politics, I think there can be little doubt on the issue.
